# MVCContrib Grid Condtional Column Showing Different Types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib-grid

I know how to show a link on an MVCContrib Grid column by using Html.ActionLink, but what I want to do is to base on the value of a field where if the field has a value = false then show text and if it has true then show a link.

It won't let me do something like this:

```
column.For(x => x.HasValue == false ? 
                x.Name : Html.ActionLink(x.Name, "MyMethod", "MyController")
```

"cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' becasue it is not a delegate type"

It lets me use Html.Raw for both conditions but when I run the app, I get the same error message

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is `x.Name` and the code above has a missing right parenthesis, is that part of the problem?

Comment: @PhilipFourie
x.Name is a string.  The missing parenthesis is not part of the problem, I just forgot to paste it.  I got it working, using something like this:

Comment: @PhilipFourie
column.For(x => x.HasAttachment ? string.Format(@"<a href=""{0}"">{1}</a>", ResolveUrl("~/MyApp/MyController/MyMethod/")) : x.Name)

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET MVC 2 you could use the [Action Syntax](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/03/01/mvccontrib-grid-part-5-the-action-syntax/):

```
column.For("Name")
      .Named("")
      .Action(item => { %>
          <td style="font-weight:bold">
              <% if (item.HasValue) { %>
                  <%= Html.Encode(item.Name) %>
              <% } else { %>
                  <%= Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "MyMethod", "MyController") %>
              <% } %>
          </td>
      <% });
```

As an alternative you could also use a partial:

```
column
    .For("Name")
    .Named("")
    .Partial("MyPartial");
```

and inside `MyPartial.ascx` perform the test.

In ASP.NET MVC 3 this has been deprecated in favor of custom columns (`columns.Custom(...)`).

Comment: Somehow the system won't let me use colum.For("Name"), I have to use column.For(item => item.HasValue) instead.  Plus, I keep getting an error message "CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'" when using something similar to your example.  To make it works, I ended up using something like this: column.For(x => x.HasAttachment ? string.Format(@"<a href=""{0}"">{1}</a>", ResolveUrl("~/MyApp/MyController/MyMethod/" = x.Name)) : x.Name)